# Java based subversion client

Tags: java, perl, svn

We have ssh access to our hosting provider, but they dont have any form of version control software installed on their machine and as ours is a shared host they will not install software for us. They do however have both Java and Perl installed and accessible to us.

What i'm after is some software that will allow me to run subversion commands from a command line. It must be written in Java and have as few dependencies outside of Java or Perl as possible.

I looked at svnKit but couldn't find the command line tool or any recent instructions on their website on how to use.

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 3):

So what if they won't install it for you. Install it yourself!

Get the sources [here](http://subversion.apache.org/download/).

Installation instructions are in the [`INSTALL`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/INSTALL) file therein.

Comment: As much as i love your answer, my boss thinks that this would be a bit of foul play. And we don't want to build our processes around having software that can be ripped out from underneath at any time.

Comment: I'm boggling at the concept that you're ok with a provider you believe might delete your files.

Comment: If it's against the TOS, that's one thing. Being afraid of getting files in your home directory deleted is another.

Comment: If an SVN written in C is against the TOS and subject to deletion, so would an SVN client written in Perl or Java.

Comment: So either you're trying to do something that's against the TOS or something that your web service provider will rip out from under you. What do you expect from us.

Comment: We figured that executing java in java environment or perl scripts in perl environment is fine. I'm not worried about them deleting files, i just don't want to design a process around having a subversion client, then have subversion taken away.

Comment: And what envioronment do you think `java` and `perl` run in?! How do you take a file away other than deleting it?

Comment: I'm boggling at the concept that you're ok with a provider you believe might take away your files.